# Need assistance tweaking javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for assistance tweaking a Javascript function I'm using on a website I'm building.

https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-headlines/index.html

I'm using the first style there where it cycles through the words and essentially what I'm trying to do is have one of the words stay on the screen a little longer than the rest so it stands out.

I'm fairly competent with programming but new to Javascript. Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//set animation timing
var animationDelay = 2500,
    //loading bar effect
    barAnimationDelay = 3800,
    barWaiting = barAnimationDelay - 3000, //3000 is the duration of the transition on the loading bar - set in the scss/css file
    //letters effect
    lettersDelay = 50,
    //type effect
    typeLettersDelay = 150,
    selectionDuration = 500,
    typeAnimationDelay = selectionDuration + 800,
    //clip effect 
    revealDuration = 600,
    revealAnimationDelay = 1500;

initHeadline();


function initHeadline() {
    //insert <i> element for each letter of a changing word
    singleLetters($('.cd-headline.letters').find('b'));
    //initialise headline animation
    animateHeadline($('.cd-headline'));
}

function singleLetters($words) {
    $words.each(function(){
        var word = $(this),
            letters = word.text().split(''),
            selected = word.hasClass('is-visible');
        for (i in letters) {
            if(word.parents('.rotate-2').length > 0) letters[i] = '<em>' + letters[i] + '</em>';
            letters[i] = (selected) ? '<i class="in">' + letters[i] + '</i>': '<i>' + letters[i] + '</i>';
        }
        var newLetters = letters.join('');
        word.html(newLetters).css('opacity', 1);
    });
}

function animateHeadline($headlines) {
    var duration = animationDelay;
    $headlines.each(function(){
        var headline = $(this);

        if(headline.hasClass('loading-bar')) {
            duration = barAnimationDelay;
            setTimeout(function(){ headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('is-loading') }, barWaiting);
        } else if (headline.hasClass('clip')){
            var spanWrapper = headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper'),
                newWidth = spanWrapper.width() + 10
            spanWrapper.css('width', newWidth);
        } else if (!headline.hasClass('type') ) {
            //assign to .cd-words-wrapper the width of its longest word
            var words = headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper b'),
                width = 0;
            words.each(function(){
                var wordWidth = $(this).width();
                if (wordWidth > width) width = wordWidth;
            });
            headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper').css('width', width);
        };

        //trigger animation
        setTimeout(function(){ hideWord( headline.find('.is-visible').eq(0) ) }, duration);
    });
}

function hideWord($word) {
    var nextWord = takeNext($word);     

    if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
        var parentSpan = $word.parent('.cd-words-wrapper');
        parentSpan.addClass('selected').removeClass('waiting'); 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            parentSpan.removeClass('selected'); 
            $word.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden').children('i').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
        }, selectionDuration);
        setTimeout(function(){ showWord(nextWord, typeLettersDelay) }, typeAnimationDelay);

    } else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('letters')) {
        var bool = ($word.children('i').length >= nextWord.children('i').length) ? true : false;
        hideLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, bool, lettersDelay);
        showLetter(nextWord.find('i').eq(0), nextWord, bool, lettersDelay);

    }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ width : '2px' }, revealDuration, function(){
            switchWord($word, nextWord);
            showWord(nextWord);
        });

    } else if ($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('loading-bar')){
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').removeClass('is-loading');
        switchWord($word, nextWord);
        setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(nextWord) }, barAnimationDelay);
        setTimeout(function(){ $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('is-loading') }, barWaiting);

    } else {
        switchWord($word, nextWord);
        setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(nextWord) }, animationDelay);
    }
}

function showWord($word, $duration) {
    if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
        showLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, false, $duration);
        $word.addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden');

    }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ 'width' : $word.width() + 10 }, revealDuration, function(){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, revealAnimationDelay); 
        });
    }
}

function hideLetter($letter, $word, $bool, $duration) {
    $letter.removeClass('in').addClass('out');

    if(!$letter.is(':last-child')) {
        setTimeout(function(){ hideLetter($letter.next(), $word, $bool, $duration); }, $duration);  
    } else if($bool) { 
        setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(takeNext($word)) }, animationDelay);
    }

    if($letter.is(':last-child') && $('html').hasClass('no-csstransitions')) {
        var nextWord = takeNext($word);
        switchWord($word, nextWord);
    } 
}

function showLetter($letter, $word, $bool, $duration) {
    $letter.addClass('in').removeClass('out');

    if(!$letter.is(':last-child')) { 
        setTimeout(function(){ showLetter($letter.next(), $word, $bool, $duration); }, $duration); 
    } else { 
        if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) { setTimeout(function(){ $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('waiting'); }, 200);}
        if(!$bool) { setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, animationDelay) }
    }
}

function takeNext($word) {
    return (!$word.is(':last-child')) ? $word.next() : $word.parent().children().eq(0);
}

function takePrev($word) {
    return (!$word.is(':first-child')) ? $word.prev() : $word.parent().children().last();
}

function switchWord($oldWord, $newWord) {
    $oldWord.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
    $newWord.removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('is-visible');
}});
```

Can someone give me an idea of how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Jonathan - and welcome to SO. Please have a quick read of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question accordingly. Specifically, your (relevant) code should be right here in the question, preferably as a stack snippet (code we can run from within the question). Also, it would be nice to highlight what kind of result/output you're currently getting vs. what you want/expect.

Comment: appreciate you pointing that out, i've just inserted the code in a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the changes that I would make.

To change the times on a specific element I would add a property on the element:

```
 <h1 class="cd-headline rotate-1">
    <span>My favourite food is</span>
    <span class="cd-words-wrapper" style="width: 128px;">
      <b class="is-visible">pizza</b>
      <b class="is-hidden" animationDelay="5000">sushi</b>
      <b class="is-hidden">steak</b>
    </span>
  </h1>
```

I would add this variable to JavaScript:

```
  var animationDelay = 2500,
      animationDelay_default = 2500, // this
      [...]
```

This first trigger would change (I'd move the setTimeout into the function):

```
setTimeout(function(){ hideWord( headline.find('.is-visible').eq(0) ) }, duration);
```

In

```
hideWord( headline.find('.is-visible').eq(0));
```

And the `hideWord` function would change like this:

```
function hideWord($word) {
    animationDelay = $word.attr("animationDelay") != undefined ? parseInt($word.attr("animationDelay")) : animationDelay_default;

    var nextWord = takeNext($word);
    setTimeout(function() {


      if ($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
        var parentSpan = $word.parent('.cd-words-wrapper');
        parentSpan.addClass('selected').removeClass('waiting');
        setTimeout(function() {
          parentSpan.removeClass('selected');
          $word.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden').children('i').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
        }, selectionDuration);
        setTimeout(function() {
          showWord(nextWord, typeLettersDelay)
        }, typeAnimationDelay);

      } else if ($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('letters')) {
        var bool = ($word.children('i').length >= nextWord.children('i').length) ? true : false;
        hideLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, bool, lettersDelay);
        showLetter(nextWord.find('i').eq(0), nextWord, bool, lettersDelay);

      } else if ($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({
          width: '2px'
        }, revealDuration, function() {
          switchWord($word, nextWord);
          showWord(nextWord);
        });

      } else if ($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('loading-bar')) {
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').removeClass('is-loading');
        switchWord($word, nextWord);
        setTimeout(function() {
          hideWord(nextWord)
        }, barAnimationDelay);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('is-loading')
        }, barWaiting);

      } else {
        switchWord($word, nextWord);
        setTimeout(function() {
          hideWord(nextWord)
        }, animationDelay);
      }


    }, animationDelay);

  }
```

[The code all together on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/jx5c3Lrg/21/) (your css is too big for the integrated snippet).

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks for the quick response and the easy solution.  Really appreciate it